# Can Dojo AMD resolve a non existing module with 'undefined' instead of failing?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I'd like to load a module that's *possibly* there.

```
Evil    requires            requires
BlackBox --------> myModule --------> mayExist
```

- If `mayExist` is not there, I don't want a failure to load `myModule`. I'd like something like a `null` or `undefined` value in the callback variable.
- By the time the AMD loader will return `myModule` to `BlackBox`, I need to know whether I can depend on `mayExist` or not. I can't really afford to first load `myModule`, then launch an aynchronous request for `mayExist` and then deal with a possible error. That's because that black box won't wait to do its evil things.

Is there some dependable way to specify in `define`'s config object that I don't want a general failure if a dependency does not exist ?

Comment: The link over [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/02/25/dojo-faq-how-can-i-conditionally-load-amd-modules/) may help you out.

Comment: `has!` can help with conditional loading on known conditions. But I see two differences :  
**1/** here my condition is simply whether `mayExist` exists or not. The existence of this file will not be related to anything functional that can be test with `has!`, and it's not anything I can control. It'll be up to the user of my framework to have this file or not.  
**2/** The `has!` plugin expects a ternary expression that has to resolve to a module in any case. I don't see a clear documented way to resolve to `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave it up to your framework user to decide, or leave an empty, valid stub for your user to override?

Assuming that's not an option, you could try inline-`require`-ing it, a la...

```
define([... "require", ...],
...
postCreate: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    try {
        require(["my/custom/Thing"], lang.hitch(this, function(Thing) {
            this.thing = new Thing();
        }));
    catch (e) {
        // do something else (or not).
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I'm very late here... That construct does not allow to guarantee an answer by the time the module is resolved, unfortunately. And since I'm building inside what you could consider a framework (the evil box), I can't provide a sound API of my choice for either dependency injection or plug-in availability testing.